# Base Price Same as Custom Option Price On Product Listing on every page

Tags: magento-1.8, price, custom-options

I want, the price on the product listing should be same as the default price of custom option.

In current scenario the product details price shows Price = Base Price + Custom Option Price.I don't have any base price so to show the price i keep base price as "0". Now if i keep base price "0", product listing price gives me "0" as price.

1) One approach >> custom attribute on product listing...How ?

2) Second approach >> remove addition of base price & custom price....How ?

In either of these or any other solutions, how can i deal with discounts.???

Please spare some thought on this issue. Let me know what can i do. I hope will get an answer this time.

Regards

Comment: +1 as this is a common issue when we assign 0 as a Base Price. I'm sorry I can't help, but I'm in the same boat as you. Did you manage to find a solution?